# How Can I get sitecore value and replace the js variable with that value ? in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

How Can I get sitecore value and  replace the js variable with that value ? in asp.net

ex: Assume sitecore field value is 4 then I need to get this value to a variable and replace the js with this value.

Comment: This is done the same way as you will have to in regular ASP.NET application -> [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4396826/468718)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Server side variable on client side and Vice versa Asp.Net and javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396804/access-server-side-variable-on-client-side-and-vice-versa-asp-net-and-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

For example, if on the current item you have a field `Title` and you want to assign its value to a JavaScript variable, you can use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var title= '@Sitecore.Context.Item["Title"]';
</script>
```

I tried it in an MVC solution and it works fine.

And for ASP.NET WebForms, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var title = '<%= Sitecore.Context.Item["Title"] %>';
</script>
```

Comment: now I need to pass this variable value to external js. and replace there variable value. actually I need to change image slider time interval should change manually.